# symfony2: how to check if form is new?

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to check if a form is new in my template, something like $form->isNew() in symfony 1.4, but i did not find a solution.

Currently, i'm using this technique:

```
{% null != entity.getId %}
```

it works, but are there other solutions which are more clean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony2 forms are less coupled to the model than symfony1 forms. Form in Symfony2 cannot be "new" or "old". It's the entity which is persisted, not the form. Forms job is to put submitted data to the model object.

Remember that model class doesn't have to be a doctrine entity (can be really an object of any class). It's up to you to define what does it mean that object is new or not (persisted or not). Again, it's not a form which is persisted.

Btw, you could check for id like this:

```
{% if entity.id %}{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 6):

I use this:

```
{% if form.vars.submitted == false %}DO WHATEVER HERE{% endif %}
```

More info in form functions and variables here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html

Comment: This is the best way imo as it doesn't rely on the presence of any specific property such as ID (not every form is tied to an entity).

Comment: Note that: It is only TRUE when a form has been submitted. It is FALSE while editing a existing entity.

Answer (score 3):

A better solution nowadays (SF3) will be:

```
{% if form.vars.data.id %}{% endif %}
```